# How to add js to a joomla template

Tags: joomla

i need to add js to a specific page in joomla. How do i do that? I cant find any option to edit the html of each page, since i also have to add some little html. How does joomla do that? i can assign a template for a specific site but then you would have to do each change twice...

I need to add a javascript file and some html to one specific site. i read the wiki and googled but i dont get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you couldn't find a page to edit is that there is only one page in a Joomla site that builds all the other pages based on the URL, menu ID, and other parameters passed in the query string.

If you only need the javascript on a single "page" then there are a couple of ways to do it depending on where the content needs to be.

If it needs to go in the main content area (the component position) then you should get an extension that allows you to put javascript inside a regular Joomla article. Then you can put what ever code and HTML you need in the article and link to it with a regular menu item.

If you want it to go in a module position, then you can simply use the Custom HTML module. If you turn off the WYSIWYG editor editor, you can put the javascript right in to the content area of the module. It does require the editor to be off though, otherwise the code will be evaluated and you will lose what ever you had in there. You can also limit where the module displays under the menu assignment selection.